# Moving averages using MongoDB's aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Given that you have a collection of documents with either a date or period (2013-01) property, what's the best way to compute moving average statistics (say 3-m avg.) using MongoDB's aggregation framework?

Answer (score 1):

It's best to run the entire aggregation at a reasonable interval, and recalculate the whole set. If you're calculating a 3 month average, setup a cronjob to run every night and calculate the average.

```
var minus3Months = new Date();
minus3Months.setMonth(now.getMonth()-3);
db.myCollection.aggreage([
    {"$match": {"createdAt": {"$gte": minus3Months}}},
    ......
])
```

Comment: How would you do that with historical data? Programmatically set time frame with multiple aggregate queries for 3month intervals for lets say 50 years? Is there a way of doing this with one query?